# How to use Airbnb's iCalendar Link Programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, icalendar

I have gotten the iCalendar link of a Airbnb listing.
When I visit that link using any browser, the browser automatically downloads the .ics iCalendar file.
I am trying to program an application that will sync with the iCalendar of that particular Airbnb listing.
I thought I should just `fetch` the iCalendar link and I can read the contents of the .ics file and parse it and process the information.

However when I try to use `isomorphic-fetch` on the same Airbnb Calendar link I am getting the following Response:

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kTransformState)]: [Object]
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/22342432.ics?s=56501a678175afddd0ef3874b7a1b28b',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}

FetchError: invalid json response body at https://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/22342432.ics?s=56501a678175afddd0ef3874b7a1b28b reason: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0
```

Ideally I would like to query that link from NODE.js (Next.js) and instead of downloading a .ics file I would like to be able to parse the info of the .ics in JSON format so I can process the data and find out which dates are available and which dates are not available for that listing....

How can I do that?

btw I used `isomorphic-fetch` npm library to do the fetching...e.g.

```
const response = await fetch(`https://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/22342432.ics?s=56501a678175afddd0ef3874b7a1b28b`);
        

        console.log('response');
        console.log(response);

        console.log('response.body', response.body);
        

        stories = await response.json();

        console.log('stories');
        console.log(stories);

        res.status(200).json(stories)

    } catch(err) {
        console.log('error')
        console.log(err)
        stories = [];

    }
```

Comment: "Parse the info of the .ICS in JSON format" doesn't make any sense, those are two completely different text formats. Do you just mean "parse the info of the .ICS file **using JavaScript**?"

Comment: @IMSoP Yes parsing the info from the .ICS file will work for me too. How do I do that? when I do fetch('URL of .ics file") I don't get the contents of the .ics file...what I get is what I showed above..... how do I fetch from the URL but be able to read the contents of the .ics file instead of something else?

Comment: Well, for starters, don't try to parse it as JSON. I don't know the library in question, but `response.json()` is not the right function if the text you're looking at isn't in JSON format. Your first step is to get the content from the URL as text; there's probably a different function on the library to do that. Then you can find (and test completely separately) a function to get data out of a string that's in iCal format.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer....
use npm package `node-ical`

```
const ical = require('node-ical');
    
    ical.fromURL(url, options, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
    });
```